# uses of named-pipes

Tags: named-pipes

Recently I was reading about named pipes; it looks really interesting and practical, however I looking on internet couldn't find a something like a list of applications or uses of named pipes.

All ideas of uses/applications of named pipes are welcome!!

thanks

Comment: Which operating system are you asking about?

Comment: in general, linux or a MS or OSX ... for me it looked interesting but I would like to know what people use it for! thx

Answer (score 1):

Most obvious one I can think of is MS-SQL.

Comment: can you explain a little bit how? tnx

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are useful for interprocess communication, that is, sending information from one process to another. Very often these days the two processes exist on the same machine, but that need not be so.

Have a look here:

http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe