# Real world examples of UNIX named pipes

Tags: named-pipes

I usually think of UNIX pipes as a quick and dirty way to interact with the console, doing things such as:

`ls | grep '\.pdf$' #list all pdfs`

I understand that it's possible to use create named pipes using `mkfifo` and `mknod`.

Are named pipes still used significantly today, or are they a relic of the past?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uses of named-pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614205/uses-of-named-pipes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are still used, although you might not notice. As a first-class file-system object provided by the operating system, a named pipe can be used by *any* program, regardless of what language it is written in, that can read and write to the file system for interprocess communication.

Specific to `bash` (and other shells), process substitution can be implemented using named pipes, and on some platforms that may be how it actually is implemented. The following

```
command < <( some_other_command )
```

is roughly identical to

```
mkfifo named_pipe
some_other_command > named_pipe &
command < named_pipe
```

and so is useful for things like POSIX-compliant shell code, which does not recognize process substitution.

---

And it works in the other direction: `command > >( some_other_command )` is

```
mkfifo named_pipe
some_other_command < named_pipe &
command > named_pipe
```

Answer (score 1):

[pianobar](https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar), the command line Pandora Radio player, uses a named pipe to provide a mechanism for arbitrary control input. If you want to control Pianobar with another app, such as [PianoKeys](https://github.com/shayne/PianoKeys), you set it up to write command strings to the FIFO file, which piano bar watches for incoming commands.

I wrote a MAMP stack app in college that we used to manage users in an LDAP database on a file server. The PHP scripts would write commands to a FIFO that a shell script running in launchd would read from and interact with the LDAP database. I had no idea what I was doing, so I don’t know if there was a better or more correct way to do it, but it worked great at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Named pipes are useful where a program would expect a path to a file as an argument as opposed to being willing to read/write with stdin and stdout, though very modern versions of bash can get around this with < ( foo ) it is still sometimes useful to have a file like object which is usable as a pipe.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "can get around this with < ( foo )" ?

Comment: @MikeVella bash allows one not to use a named pipe in some cases by allowing you to put < ( commandname ) as an argument, this then acts as if the output of that command had been piped into a named pipe and the path of that named pipe had been passed to the command on the left.